# Failed to load PhantomJS module

Tags: javascript, node.js, html-pdf

I am facing the issue

```
html-pdf: Failed to load PhantomJS module. You have to set the path to the PhantomJS binary using 'options.phantomPath'\\nAssertionError [ERR_ASSERTION]: html-pdf: Failed to load PhantomJS module. You have to set the path to the PhantomJS binary using 'options.phantomPath'\\n    at new PDF (/home/node/source/node_modules/html-pdf/lib/pdf.js:40:3)\\n    at Object.createPdf [as create] (/home/node/source/node_modules/html-pdf/lib/index.js:10:14)
```

I have tried many solutions that are available over internet, still nothing helps.

I am using

1. node 16 docker container
2. html-pdf: "^3.0.1"
3. "phantomjs-prebuilt": "2.1.4"